# Why am I getting this error while importing this Rust module?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Goal: Get this to import successfully so I can start using the functions.

Rust Code:

```
pub use crate::pqcrypto_dilithium::*;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "project"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
pqcrypto-dilithium = "0.4.5"
```

Error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::pqcrypto_dilithium`
 --> main.rs:1:16
  |
1 | pub use crate::pqcrypto_dilithium::*;
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ maybe a missing crate `pqcrypto_dilithium`?

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
```

Comment: How do you build this code?

Comment: Do not post text as images.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Remove `crate::` from the `use` line.

Comment: I updated the code. To reproduce this, simply make a .rs file, copy and paste the Rust code, make a Cargo.toml file and copy and paste, then run.

Comment: New error I am getting

Comment: error[E0432]: unresolved import `pqcrypto_dilithium`
 --> main.rs:1:9
  |
1 | pub use pqcrypto_dilithium::*;
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ maybe a missing crate `pqcrypto_dilithium`?

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.

Comment: "then run" what exactly? There are at least two ways to trigger building for Rust code, we can't know which one do you use.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki, this shouldn't make any difference, since at the crate root `foo` and `crate::foo` are equivalent.

Comment: @Cerberus Not if `foo` is an external crate.

Comment: What strange here is that rustc is suggesting "maybe missing an external crate?"

Comment: @Cerberus The .rs file. Not with cargo.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yeah, that's the strange bit.

Comment: Which makes me suspect that this is not the actual code/error. I tried to reproduce online and failed; I have no time to try to reproduce locally now.

Comment: If you're "running the .rs file" (whatever it means) without cargo and doesn't read the Cargo.toml yourself during this, then Cargo.toml is ignored, together with all the dependencies.

Comment: So do you think I should try to run it via Cargo @Cerberus

Answer (score 1):

The proper code to use is the following:

```
pub use pqcrypto_dilithium::*;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Comment: `pub use` will re-export everything from `pqcrypto_dilithium` into your crate. You probably just want `use pqcrypto_dilithium::*;`.

Comment: This is the error I got when I tried that.

Comment: warning: unused import: `pqcrypto_dilithium::*`
 --> src\main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use pqcrypto_dilithium::*;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

warning: `project` (bin "project") generated 1 warning

Comment: The warning is correct. You're not using anything from `pycrypto_dilithium` yet since you just have a single `println!`. Rust is pretty aggressive about warning about unused imports, variables, etc. You can ignore the warning since presumably you're going to use it soon.

Comment: Question, in VSCode, is there anyway I can automate the line "cargo run", so I can jus hit the play button and it uses cargo bu default?

Comment: @user404 I think rust-analyzer has a Code Len "Run | Debug" on top of `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not start with `crate::`.

`crate::` means starting looking from this working crate's root.

If you have a module named `pqcrypto_dilithium` in the project root, then it will work. Just like:

```
// main.rs/lib.rs
mod pqcrypto_dilithium { ... }
pub use crate::pqcrypto_dilithium::*;

--- 

// main.rs/lib.rs
mod wrap {
  mod pqcrypto_dilithium { ... }
}
// This is not going to work
pub use crate::pqcrypto_dilithium::*;
// Works
pub use crate::wrap::pqcrypto_dilithium::*;
```

Finally, in your case: `pqcrypto_dilithium` is a dep, an external crate. So you can not do that.

But you can simply do:

```
pub use pqcrypto_dilithium::*;
```

Comment: `pub use` will re-export everything from `pqcrypto_dilithium` into the OP's crate. They probably just want `use pqcrypto_dilithium::*;`.